# Audio Not Playing When Button Clicked In Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to play an audio sound when I click on **Delete** button. I have also written the external JavaScript file and linked it with Flask.

**index.html**

```
<a href="/delete/{{todoitem.item_id}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="playDelSound()">Delete</a>
```

**app.js**

```
function playDelSound() {
        var delSound = new Audio("/static/delete.mp3");
        delSound.play();
}
```

But when I click the **Delete** button, the sound is not playing.

Comment: first you could check in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox if there is error message in JavaScript Console. You can also use `alert()` to see if it will run your function when you click it. If you don't block link then it may not have time to play it because it loads new page - `/delete`.

Comment: @furas: I have checked the Javascript Console. There is no error.

Comment: I would expect that it simply load new page - when you click link `/delete/...` - so it removes all code from memory and it can't run it.

Comment: @furas: When clicking the "Delete" button that particular item got deleted. That is operated in Flask routes. py

Comment: @furas: I sent an email to you. Can you please check that email regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click link then web browser reloads page and it removes from memory code which should play sound.

You would have to catch link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sound('{{item}}')">JAVASCRIPT LINK</a>
```

play sound and redirect/reload page after sound.

```
function sound(item) {
    var audio = new Audio('/static/audio_file.mp3');
    audio.onended = function() { window.location.href="/delete/" + item; }
    audio.play();
}
```

Minimal working code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<a href="/" onclick="sound()">NORMAL LINK</a><br>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sound('{{item}}')">JAVASCRIPT LINK</a>

<script>
function sound(item) {
    //alert("SOUND");
    var audio = new Audio('/static/audio_file.mp3');
    // reload after audio 
    audio.onended = function() { window.location.href="/delete/" + item; }
    audio.play();
}
</script>
''', item="somevalue")

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, adding a time.sleep(5) before the redirection to the route that is triggered by te button gives you time to reproduce your audio, you can modify the time that you need according to your audio.

`time.sleep(5)`

`return redirect(url_for('YOUR ROUTE'))`